# Apply Variable Index Across Columns of An Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, multiple-columns

I have a 2x3 array like the following:

```
import numpy as np    
y = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
```

I want to index one element from each column. For example, the 1st element in column 1, the 2nd element in column 2, and the 1st element in column 3. The output should look like this:

```
ans = [1,5,3]
```

I tried to use

```
y[0,1,0]
```

and

```
np.take(y, [0,1,0,1], axis=1)
```

but neither worked. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

you should access it this way :

```
>>> y
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
>>> y[0,0]
1
>>> y[1,1]
5
>>> y[0,2]
3
>>> [y[0,0], y[1,1],y[0,2]]
[1, 5, 3]
```

numpy array is reference with coordinates [x,y] in your array.
Then you can find some strategy to solve a specific problem, with a specific logic :

```
>>> y
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
>>> res=[y[j%2,j] for j in range(y.shape[1])]
>>> res
[1, 5, 3]
>>> y = np.array([[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]])
>>> res=[y[j%2,j] for j in range(y.shape[1])]
>>> res
[1, 5, 1, 7, 1, 9, 1, 11]
```

EDIT :

```
>>> idxCol=[0,1,0]
>>> res=[y[idxCol[i],i] for i in range(len(idxCol))]
>>> res
[1, 5, 3]
```

Comment: Hi Dadep, in my initial question the index is something like [0,1,0], but in my real problem, the index is given, such as Index = [9,2,11,3,...]. So I probably need two 'For Loops'? <<< start of code >>> res=[y[i,j] for j in range(y.shape[1]) and for i in Index ] <<< end of code >>> I know the code I wrote is incorrect. Could you show the correct way to write this line code with two for loops?

Comment: see edit in my post if you are sure that you index list have the same size than number of column it should work this way

Answer (score 0):

```
In [448]: y = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
In [450]: idx = [0,1,0]
```

`idx` selects the row for successive columns, so you need to pair it with a column indexing list (or array):

```
In [454]: y[idx,[0,1,2]]
Out[454]: array([1, 5, 3])
In [455]: y[idx, np.arange(y.shape[1])]
Out[455]: array([1, 5, 3])
```

It may help to visualize this by taking the 'transpose' of the 2 lists:

```
In [456]: list(zip([0,1,0],[0,1,2]))
Out[456]: [(0, 0), (1, 1), (0, 2)]
In [457]: [y[i,j] for i,j in Out[456]]
Out[457]: [1, 5, 3]
```

You'd have to do it this way with lists, but `numpy` does the pairing for you.